# How to declare an empty query in web2py

Tags: web2py

I want to construct a dynamic query like this:
query = (field1==val1)&((field2==val2)|(field2==val3)|...|(field2==valn))
val1 to valn are saved in a list say list_value.
My code would be something like:

```
query = field1==val1
query1 = ''                              <--Problem 
list_value=[val2, va3, ..., valn]
for val in list_value:
    query1 |= field2==val
query = query&query1
```

But the problem here is that the query is not constructed correctly. It seems like the problem of empty query1 declaration.
Is there any clean way to write this piece of code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest alternative is to use the `.belongs` method:

```
query = (field1 == val1) & field2.belongs(list_value)
```

If you want to stick with your original approach, you could do something like:

```
query1 = reduce(lambda a, b: a | b, (field2 == v for v in list_value))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! `.belongs` resolved my problem. It is a better and neater implementation. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

A bit of hack would be:

```
q = False
q |= db.mytable.myfield != 'value'
```

which yields

```
<Query ((`rules`.`id` IS NOT NULL) OR 0)>
```